# Angular 2 Application reacting very slowly only while Chrome DevTools is open

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools, paint

My Angular 2 Application is slow to respond (1-5 seconds) to key input, button clicks, tabbing across inputs, etc. *only* when Chrome Developer Tools is open.  Material 2 animations also become slow and choppy.

I've been developing this application for three months, and use Chrome DevTools every day. This issue cropped up seemingly overnight.

What I know:

- I stashed all pending application changes to revert my application to a time when this was not a problem.  The issue persisted.
- Chrome DevTools doesn't seem to slow down any other application (ie. google inbox, google maps) in the same browser session.
- **Maddeningly, when I run the DevTools' Timeline "Record" to try to gain visibility into the issue, the issue disappears and the page reacts at normal speed again!**  I assume this is the best clue that I have, but I don't know the internal workings of DevTools well enough to know how "Timeline Record" changes things.
- I've restarted Chrome and deleted all cached data.
- Nothing of the sort happens in Firefox or IE when I open the Developer tools in those.

Any recommendations on where to look next would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try testing on another version of Chrome like Canary or [portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/)

Comment: Have exactly the same issue with Angular 7/Chrome 73. Can't reinstall as it's controlled by admins :(

Comment: @altso Do a full reboot of your system. I know it sounds dumb but that's what solved this for me eventually a few years ago. Never sure what it was, some memory-leak or bad state. But the full reboot fixed it.

Comment: @DanielPatrick thanks for the suggestion. Full reboot did not help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Final answer:

Remove all breakpoints

[image]

Even if they're not getting hit this fixed it for me and got performance back to normal.

May be a bigger issue if you have logging breakpoints - so try deleting those first if you're attached to your breakpoints.

---

#### Previous answers:

I came up with a workaround - although still not really figured out what is actually wrong.

I also discovered a bunch of tools I didn't even know existed that I'd skipped over before - they're under `More tools`.

Start by opening the `Performance Monitor`. This shows a nice CPU graph isolated for your Chrome tab - the Windows task manager is as useless as it ever was.

[image]

This is the behavior I got when choosing a date from `mat-calendar`. No other logic running - just selecting a date. I removed everything from `app-component` and just put a `mat-calendar` and it took ten seconds to change the date!

Other controls are generally fine. I could open dialogs, use combo boxes etc. and nice and fast. But selecting a date gave me this nonsense:

[image]

I tried emptying local storage, clearing cache, etc. and then I changed port number for my website. I simply changed `dev.example.com:44300` to `dev.example.com:44301` - in other words Chrome now thought it was a different website.

This is what it looked like after I switched port number.

[image]

I also got the same effect using a [reverse proxy server](https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/quickstart/) - which put my local machine on the internet - so I could try to duplicate the issue from other machines. I could not.

So hope that helps someone - still no clue what's in the cache for this server that is having such a massive impact on performance. But for sure it's not just my code.

---

Here's a few other things to try:

#### Test with `--aot` flag

This didn't make a difference to me, but good to narrow things down.

#### Add some controls that don't do anything (as a control)

This way you can find if some specific action or control is causing the slow down. You should of course be able to toggle these instantly.

Just toggle them on and off, hide something.

```
<mat-radio-group>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="false">
        bloop
    </mat-radio-button> 
    <mat-radio-button [value]="false">
        bloop bloop
    </mat-radio-button> 
</mat-radio-group>
```

#### Enable Rendering debugging options

[image]

#### Make sure you aren't re-rendering the whole page constantly

The rendering option above will show this to some extent, but one thing I like to do is just add a random text box - type in it and if the text subsequently disappears you know that control has been rerendered.

```
 <!-- yes, just a standard text box -->
 <input type="text"/>
```

#### Just hide things with *ngIf="false"

Hide controls (yours and third party) and see if anything is causing problems.

For me I'm currently suspecting `mat-calendar` is causing issues - but I'm still thoroughly confused as to why enabling 'Record' makes the problem non existent.

Comment: The breakpoint has been exactly my issue, more specifically it was a conditional breakpoint that wasn't fired anymore, the heavy lag appeared in later executions and the devtools really should highlight this explicitly, as profiling and any other measures didn't pointed to this being such a massive issue.

Comment: @Fyrestar another thing I’ve noticed recently. If you are simply stopped on a breakpoint with certain animation running, such as a mat-spinner it can take up huge amount of CPU. The animations don’t get paused when the breakpoint is hit and for some reason it’s doing something that kills performance. Especially a problem if you end up with several instances all paused on a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue, but I'll never know what was causing it.  Likely a setting that I had accidentally changed.

I deleted the Chrome App and reinstalled, everything is back to normal.  I'm going to leave this question open in case anyone else has this problem or wants to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for every web app to run slowly with Chrome dev tools opened.

Especially if you have inspect tab open, that it's like a new page opened in the same time + has animations on any block render.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer BUT I'm getting the same exact behavior the OP is getting - including the crazy fact that enabling 'Record' mode seemingly fixes it. In my case it's switching between two radio buttons. I have no clue what's going on! It's bad to the extent that I get warnings that events are timing out. There is definitely definitely some way of messing up Chrome that makes it super super sluggish with devtools open. Also getting the same with Canary :-/ I'm talking 4-5 seconds to switch a radio button with angular material controls vs. instant.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue today at a colleagues workstation. Turned out that it was a chrome-extension (don't remember, something with "ghost" in its name). So maybe try out using guest-mode and check whether the issue still occurs. If it doesn't, successively reactivate the extensions to see which one is causing the problems. If it still occurs, follow the other proposed approaches.